# Can I limit users to a specific range and zoom level on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, range, coordinates, limit

I'm implementing a Google Map on a web-page. For the purpose of this project, I want to limit how far users can drag the map, so that they can only view a certain area that falls within two co-ordinates (one specifies north-west, the other, south-east, if you get my meaning).

What's the best way to implement this using the Google Maps API?

Is there a method I can call that will do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method does what you want: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm