# Can I limit users to a specific range and zoom level on Bing Maps?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Similar to [Can I limit users to a specific range and zoom level on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572404/can-i-limit-users-to-a-specific-range-and-zoom-level-on-google-maps) except with Bing Maps.

I don't see anything in the [API](http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3) for it specifically, so I'm not sure that it is easily done without overriding some method (and I don't know which one at that). I'm only working in javascript, not silverlight or any serverside technology.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136180/how-to-temporaily-block-map-zoom-using-bing-maps-api seems relevant.

Comment: @Mike True, but it doesn't seem to help limit the lat-lon shifting on one zoom level does it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but they don't make it easy. You need to listen to the mouse move event.

```
function LimitMove(e)
  {
     if (/* is map inside valid bounds check */)
     {
         return true; //true means we will handle the event (do nothing)
     }
     return false; //false means let the map do the default action (move)
  }

map.AttachEvent("onmousemove", LimitMove);
```

Comment: I ... don't know how you got `Use the following URL templates to get a static map. You can also display a route on a static map.` from "I want to limit how far they can scroll and zoom the map" ... but I'm willing to go out on a limb here and ask what about that seemed reasonable to you.

Comment: tongue n cheek my friend, you want a map that you can't move ;-)

Comment: No, at appropriate zoom levels they should be able to pan it. Think: Only look at a map of the state of Utah.

Comment: What version of the Bing Map API are you using 6.3 and lower is very different.

Comment: @Daniel 6.3 as I noted in the post (via link)

Comment: do you have any questions about the revised answer? The solution I posted is for 6.3

Comment: Oy, that's what I was afraid I was gonna have to do. That is great (as it were).